# build new table from rows in astropy

Tags: python, astropy

I am trying to cut out several selected objects in a astronomical catalog (FITS file) using the python package astropy. My question is how to cut out these objects and save them in a new catalog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convert them to a `astropy.table.Table` object:

```
from astropy.table import Table
orig_catalogue = Table.read('filename.fits')
```

and then select your targets (using indexing. i.e. to find all the objects that are more interesting than 100) and write them to a new fits file:

```
new_catalogue = orig_catalogue[orig_catalogue['interesting'] > 100]
new_catalogue.write('new_filename.fits')
```

Comment: Thanks. But my problem is that I don't have a specific field to index. Instead, I want to select objects by a function `selection() ` . Maybe I have to append the catalog to include an extra column showing it is selected or not?